# React router url path for unique item

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on react shopping cart app and can't find/figure it out how to make unique URL paths for unique items in my application. I've managed to display `props.match.params.id` in child component where my `<Route>` looks like this `<Route exact path="/product/:id" component={Product}/>` in parent component. But now I have an array of objects called `items` in the state of parent component and I would like to render child component depending on url `:id`. Every item in my array has an id, but how can I "bind?" url :id and items id in my array? The point is that when you click on the image or name of the item in the real online shop it brings you to a more detailed page of this unique item, and I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using something like this

```
const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
items.map(item =>
    <Route exact path=`/product/${item.id}` component={Product} />
)
```

Resulting path

```
/product/1
/product/2
/product/3
```

Comment: Could you explain what `${id}` is changing ?

Comment: Can you post your post your code on any online editor?

Comment: And what about mapping an array? It does not tell me anything how to solve my problem.

Comment: In the sandbox example an array of object is being mapped